# How are pointers to data members allocated/stored in memory?

Tags: c++, class, memory-management

This is one topic that is not making sense to me. Pointers to data members of a class can be declared and used. However,

1. What is the logic that supports the idea ? [I am not talking about the syntax, but the logic of this feature]
2. Also,if i understand this correctly, this would imply an indefinite/variable amount of memory being allocated at the pointer initialization as any number of objects may exist at that time. Also, new objects may be created and destroyed during runtime. Hence, in effect, a single statement will cause a large number of allocations/deallocations. This seems rather counter-intuitive as compared to the rest of the language. Or is my understanding of this incorrect ? I dont think there is any other single initialization statement that will implicitly affect program execution as widely as this.
3. Lastly, how is memory allocated to these pointers ? Where are they placed with respect to objects ? Is it possible to see physical memory addresses of these pointers ?

Comment: Well, for starters, insufficient depth in coverage of this concept by my Professor, plus i did not find anything to suggest otherwise in C++ : The Standard Reference and another coursebook..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A single declaration of a pointer to a data member, creates pointers for every object of that class.

No. It creates a pointer to a member (which can be though of as an offset from the base of object)
You can then use it with a pointer to an object to get that member.

```
struct S
{
    int  x;
    int  y;
};

int S::*  ptrToMember = &S::x;  // Pointer to a member.

S   obj;
int*      ptrToData   = &obj.x; // Pointer to object
                                // that happens to be a member
```

Notice in creating the pointer to a member we don't use an object (we just use the type information). So this pointer is an offset into the class to get a specific member.

You can access the data member via a pointer or object.

```
(obj.*ptrToMember)   = 5;   // Assign via pointer to member (requires an object)
*ptrToData           = 6;   // Assign via pointer already points at object.
```

> Why does this happen as opposed to a single pointer being created to point to only one specific instance of the class ?

That is called a pointer.
A similar but parallel concept (see above).

> What is the logic that supports the idea ?

Silly example:

```
 void addOneToMember(S& obj, int S::* member) { (obj.*member) += 1; }

 void addOneToX(S& obj)    { addOneToMember(obj, &Obj::x);}
 void addOneToY(S& obj)    { addOneToMember(obj, &Obj::y);}
```

> Also,if i understand this correctly, this would imply an indefinite/variable amount of memory being allocated at the pointer initialization as any number of objects may exist at that time.

No. Because a pointer to a member is just an offset into an object. You still need the actual object to get the value.

> Lastly, how is memory allocated to these pointers ?

Same way as other objects. There is nothing special about them in terms of layout.
But the actual layout is implementation defined. So there is no way of answering this question without referring to the compiler. But it is really of no use to you.

> Is it possible to see physical memory addresses of these pointers ?

Sure. They are just like other objects.

```
 // Not that this will provide anything meaningful.
 std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ptrToMember), sizeof(ptrToMember));

 // 1) take the address of the pointer to member.
 // 2) cast to char* as required by write.
 // 3) pass the size of the pointer to member 

 // and you should write the values printed out.
 // Note the values may be non printable but I am sure you can work with that
 // Also note the meaning is not useful to you as it is compiler dependent.
```

Comment: Thank you, @Loki Astari forthe detailed answer. What i still cant understand is this -> Even if it is just an offset, the identifier declared to refer to that offset will have to be related to the offset somewhere in memory. Hence, even if only a single copy is required for all class instances,that one copy will have to be stored somewhere. Where is that stored ?

Comment: @AshRj: As I mentioned. A member pointer is an object just like everything else. So where you declare it is where it is stored. In the above example: `ptrToMember` is a variable; where you declare that is where it is stored. There is nothing special above pointer to members. So in the above example it is stored just beside `ptrToData`

Comment: @AshRj: Note: You can think of it as an offset. But technically there is a tiny bit more information that may be needed. That is why I keep mentioning that the information is not very useful.

Comment: What i was asking is that, is it stored along with static members of the class [asa single copy is required] ? or as a separate entity/variable ?

Comment: @AshRj: There is nothing special about it. Think of it this way. If you declare a variable of type `int`; where is that stored? The same way as pointer to member; it is stored at the point where you declare the variable. There is no magic to where it is placed. You may think the answer is roundabout. But if you give a specific example of some code then I can give you a specific answer about where it is stored. But if you ask very general questions I can only answer you in a very general way.

Answer (score 4):

> A single declaration of a pointer to a data member, creates pointers for every object of that class.

No, it does not. A pointer to a member is a special object that is very different from a pointer; it is a lot more similar to an offset. Given a pointer to an object of the class and a member pointer, you'd be able to get the value of a member; without the pointer to an object of a class a pointer to a member is useless.

Questions 2 and 3 stem from the same basic misunderstanding.

Comment: Again, what is it if it isnt a pointer ?
Plus,memory will be allocated for this special object each time an instance of the class is created, hence my second question holds.
And again,third question depends on the nature of these special objects..

Comment: @AshRj In most instances, it is a small positive integer. Allocating instances of a class has nothing to do with allocating pointers to members (unless a pointer to a member is also a member of a class, in which case a space for a small int is allocated).

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight. Along with Loki's answer, I understand what you are saying.
I just have one small issue with this, as mentioned under Loki's answer.

Comment: @AshRj " is it stored along with static members of the class [as a single copy is required] ? or as a separate entity/variable" It is not "stored" unless you store it in a variable. In this respect, a member pointer is similar to `sizeof`: the compiler knows its value, and you can obtain it, but until you store it, it is not stored anywhere.

Comment: Are you not contradicting @Loki Astari 

"A member pointer is an object just like everything else. So where you declare it is where it is stored." 

??

Comment: @AshRj No, we are saying the same thing. It is an object in the sense that you *can* store it. Think of a number `5`: you can make a local variable of type `int` and store `5` in it; you can also make a member variable of type `int` and store `5` in it. You can make a static member or non-member variable of type `int`, and store `5` in it. Member pointer is a similar thing: compiler can calculate its value for you at compile time, but it is up to you to store it. You can think of it as a type-safe version of [`offsetof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/offsetof/).

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight for the extended explanation. I think i finally understand it. Calling it a pointer seems a misnomer ..

Answer (score 0):

Internally, for a class that does not have virtual bases, a pointer-to-member-data just has to hold the offset of the data member from the start of an object of that type. With virtual bases it's a bit more complicated, because the location of the virtual base can change, depending on the type of the most-derived object. Regardless, there's a small amount of data involved, and when you dereference the pointer-to-data-member the compiler generates appropriate code to access it.